# Slick Slider. Как сделать такую галерею?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[Slick Slider](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Большая картинка это слайдер, под ней миниатюры, которые идут по мере добавления в низ. При нажатии на миниатюру она показывается в большом слайдере.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Ну например...
У нас есть список изображений. Это, скажем, массив. При первоначальной загрузке страницы верхнее больше изображение не будет никак сдвинуто. Активный слайд -- №0.

По щелчку мы меняем у верхнего большого блока left: slideIndex * верхнийБлокWidth

У верхнего блока стоит анимация изменения left. Он красиво все прокрутит до нужной позиции